# Gradle dependency visible only for annotation processor

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

I want to add a dependency to Gradle project that is visible to the annotation processor during the processing.

But at the same time I do not want this dependency to be accessible from the source code.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a recent version of Gradle, then annotation processor dependencies are declared in a separate configuration `annotationProcessor` that is only resolved for that purpose.

Versions prior to 4.6 used to find them from the compile classpath, and if you have to use old versions, I don't think there is much you can do.

Example for 4.6+:

```
dependencies {
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'
}
```

If your annotation processor requires any other dependencies for compiling your source code, you have no choice but to add them to the compile classpath, which will make them visible in an IDE. But you can use the `compileOnly` configuration to limit the scope so they won't be visible at runtime or selected as a transitive dependency. Example:

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10'
}
```

Comment: Regarding the last proposal of `compileOnly` scope, what if I use for dependencies of my annotation processor the same scope - `annotationProcessor`? Will it work?